# c# modifying routes in api controller

Tags: c#, controller, get, routes

I have this controller

```
    [Route("api/controller/method/{a}/{b}")]
    public string Get(string a,string b)
    {
        return a+"__"+b;
    }
```

It works only when I send this type of request in browser

> api/controller/method/a/b

How can I modify controller so I could send such type of request:

> api/controller/method?a=a&b=b

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from the example you showed, you want to use **query format** to pass the values. You can achieve this like this:

```
[HttpGet("api/controller/method")]
public string Get([FromQuery]string a, [FromQuery]string b)
{
    return a+"__"+b;
}
```